# Yii2: Caching Active Record Relations

Tags: php, caching, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to cache relation model from within the relation function itself. I'm wondering if this is a best practice:

```
public function getProgram()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Program::className(), ['id' => 'program_id'])->cache(5);
    }
```

The problem is that it seems to work on my local machine, which has php 7.1, but gives errors on production, which has php 5.6. The error is:

**Message:**

```
yii\base\InvalidParamException: common\models\MyEvent has no relation named "program".
```

**Trace:**

```
yii\base\UnknownMethodException: Calling unknown method: yii\db\ActiveQuery::cache()
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php", line 294, in __call
  File "/var/www/my-application/common/models/MyEvent.php", line 648, in cache
  File "/var/www/my-application/common/models/MyEvent.php", line 648, in getProgram
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php", line 1211, in getRelation
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQueryTrait.php", line 200, in normalizeRelations
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQueryTrait.php", line 167, in findWith
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQuery.php", line 212, in populate
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php", line 218, in all
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQuery.php", line 133, in all
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/data/ActiveDataProvider.php", line 116, in prepareModels
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/data/BaseDataProvider.php", line 101, in prepare
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/data/BaseDataProvider.php", line 114, in getModels
  File "/var/www/my-application/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php", line 224, in actionHomeApi
  File "<internal>", line unknown, in call_user_func_array
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php", line 57, in runWithParams
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php", line 157, in runAction
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php", line 528, in runAction
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php", line 103, in handleRequest
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php", line 386, in run
  File "/var/www/my-application/frontend/web/index.php", line 19, in <main>
yii\base\InvalidParamException: common\models\MyEvent has no relation named "program".
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php", line 1214, in getRelation
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQueryTrait.php", line 200, in normalizeRelations
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQueryTrait.php", line 167, in findWith
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQuery.php", line 212, in populate
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php", line 218, in all
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveQuery.php", line 133, in all
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/data/ActiveDataProvider.php", line 116, in prepareModels
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/data/BaseDataProvider.php", line 101, in prepare
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/data/BaseDataProvider.php", line 114, in getModels
  File "/var/www/my-application/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php", line 224, in actionHomeApi
  File "<internal>", line unknown, in call_user_func_array
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php", line 57, in runWithParams
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php", line 157, in runAction
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php", line 528, in runAction
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php", line 103, in handleRequest
  File "/var/www/my-application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php", line 386, in run
  File "/var/www/my-application/frontend/web/index.php", line 19, in <main>
```

Comment: There's no such usage. What the `cache()` method does is to turn on and off query cache when calling the callback. Note that `hasOne()` doesn't perform any DB query. So this has no effect. You can specify `->with()` on the query so the relation is fetched together with the main query.

Comment: The confusing part is that calling cache() on the query actually has an effect. With php 7.1 it works like a charm, but with 5.6 it throws an exception. 

It even throws the same exception on: 

Org::find()->where(['id' => $this->org_id])->cache(10)->one();